# Is there any way to fix bad currency read?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, currency

I would like to scrape prices of items on steam community market with my python and beautifulsoup but when I scrape one the currency ends up as swedish crowns is there any way to change that to eur?

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests .get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/USP-S%20%7C%20Blueprint%20%28Factory%20New%29').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
skin_name = soup.find('span', class_ = 'market_listing_item_name').text
sm = soup.find('span', class_ = 'market_listing_price').text.replace('                      ','sm ')

print(skin_name, sm)
```

Comment: Maybe Steam shows the currency based on the request language. Can you see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30561260/9997212) work?

Comment: NVM i know that i commented that it works but i dont know why but now with the same code its not working again