# Python Request module is making calls to Youtube Italy, why and how to fix it?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, youtube

I'm developping a **scraper** to get some data from youtube videos. I am from Spain and I am getting the songs that are present in a video, my code starts like this:

```
url = f'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={vid}'
page = requests.get(url).text
```

The main problem is that later I compare the text in the page with some Spanish strings, like `Con licencia cedida a YouTube por`. But now, I'm getting this text in Italian, like `Concesso in licenza a YouTube da`. Why? I've realized that I had youtube location in Italiy, I have changed to Spain and I have delete all the *pycache* folders from the project and from the request module, but it continues getting the Italian version. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible ways to deal with this problem:

- Remove the package and reinstall it:

  ```sh
  pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall requests
  ```
- define the port to request from:

  ```py
  import requests


  vid = "xRqqOK3IWcE"
  ip_port = "80.59.199.213:8080"
  headers = {
    "User-Agent": (
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
        '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36')
  }

  proxy = {
     'http':f"http://{ip_port}",
     'https':f"https://{ip_port}"
  }

  url = f'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={vid}'

  page = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxy, verify=False).text
  ```

Comment: I have already tried reinstalling the package and it still behaves the same. I noticed that if I open a youtube window in incognito mode, regardless of the browser I use, it always says Italy. I think this is related to my problem. BTW, where does this ip_port come from?

Comment: @fullfine The IP comes from googling proxy IP addresses in Spain

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I solved - thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30561394/12511801).

If you're using the `requests` library, then, one option is to specify the language, as follows:

```
headers = {"Accept-Language": "es-MX"}
url = f'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={vid}'
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
```